# avoidbreak is not correctly working in pdflib 8

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding, pdflib

I have a text, the word "*Versicherungs-Lebenslagen*" should only break at the hyphen. This works, but the world *Lebenslagen* should stay in the same line, if there is enough space.
In my picture, there word is in the next line.

[image: avoid linebreaking with pdflib]

My pdflib code which i read in the [API DOC, page 86](http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-8.0.6-API-reference.pdf) is:

```
haben wir Services für alle <avoidbreak=true>„Versicherungs<avoidbreak=false>-<avoidbreak=true>Lebenslagen“<avoidbreak=false> eingerichtet:
```

i also used the tags `<avoidbreak>` and `<noavoidbreak>` as i have read it in the [java examples for pdflib 9](http://www.pdflib.com/en/pdflib-cookbook/text-output/avoid-linebreaking/)

```
haben wir Services für alle <avoidbreak>„Versicherungs<noavoidbreak>-<avoidbreak>Lebenslagen“<noavoidbreak> eingerichtet:
```

Anyone know this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, this is related to the special quotation marks you use. The “ ([Unicode U+201C](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=201C) ) is defined as an opening/left character. As result, the textflow line break algorithm do not break directly afterwards.

You can workaround this, when you re-define the character class of this characters.

```
tf = p.create_textflow("haben wir Services f&uuml;r alle 
        <avoidbreak=true>&#x201E;Versicherungs<avoidbreak=false>-
        <avoidbreak=true>Lebenslagen&#x201c;<avoidbreak=false> eingerichtet:", 
    "fontname Arial encoding=unicode fontsize=20 charref 
        charclass={ close U+201C open U+201E}");
p.fit_textflow(tf, 50, 500, 350, 700, "showborder");
```

(you should use this code directly in the hello.java sample or so)

Please see also PDFlib 8 Tutorial, chapter 8.2.8 "Controlling the standard Linebreak Algorithm" for further details on this.